# How to set the in initial value of the section in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created the section in HTML

```
<td>
                <select name="sel" id="sel"> 
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">-Choice-</option> 
                    <option value="1">Package1</option> 
                    <option value="2">package2</option> 
                    <option value="3">package3</option>
                </select> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="textOne">£ 5.00 </p> 
                <p id="textTwo">£ 10.00 </p> 
                <p id="textFive">£ 15.00 </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="textThree">pack1</p>
                <p id="textFour">pack2</p>
                <p id="textSix">pack3</p>
            </td>
```

And what I want is to hide everything at the beginning, but at the beginning, it show me everything on the page, And that is my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function $(obj){
  return document.getElementById(obj);
} 
function show(objid){
  $(objid).style.display='inline';
} 
function hidden(objid){
  $(objid).style.display='none';
} 
function doit(){ 
  var sel_val=$('sel').value; 
  if(sel_val==3){
    hidden('textOne');
    hidden('textTwo');
    hidden('textThree');
    hidden('textFour');
    show('textFive');
    show('textSix');
  } 
  if(sel_val==0){
    hidden('textOne');
    hidden('textTwo');
    hidden('textThree');
    hidden('textFour');
    hidden('textFive');
    hidden('textSix');
  } 
  if(sel_val==1){
    show('textOne');
    hidden('textTwo');
    show('textThree');
    hidden('textFour');
    hidden('textFive');
    hidden('textSix');
  } 
  if(sel_val==2){
    hidden('textOne');
    show('textTwo');
    hidden('textThree');
    show('textFour');
    hidden('textFive');
    hidden('textSix');
  } 
} 
window.onload=function(){
  var sel=document.getElementById("sel");
  sel.onchange=doit;
}
</script>
<!-- show different<p> for different options -->
```

How can I change the code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You can most certainly use Javascript to do this. And your question title should say "new row" instead of column.

Comment: explore your html markup, especially  <table>

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: guys I have edit the question to add my code and what I have tried on it, it should work well but it doesn't